# How to verify RSA key length in Go?

Tags: go, cryptography, rsa, private-key

I'm setting up a https server in Go using the following function.

```
err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(":8080", key, cert, nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("error...")
}
```

Where key and cert are respectively self-signed key and certificate files.
My problem is that for security I need to validate they self-signed key to have a 2048 bits size (or more).
How can I securely and cleanly check for this in Go?

Comment: Stat the file size?

Comment: @zerkms: that doesn't seem right. what if there's extra PEM blocks, or the key and cert are in the same file?

Comment: Long story short I want to get something similar like the output of executing
"openssl rsa -text -noout -in key.pem" for which the first line of the output of this command is like this "Private-Key: (1024 bit)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/ecdsa"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/tls"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    certFile := "/tmp/cert.pem"
    keyFile := "/tmp/key.pem"

    cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(certFile, keyFile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var bitLen int
    switch privKey := cert.PrivateKey.(type) {
    case *rsa.PrivateKey:
        bitLen = privKey.N.BitLen()
    case *ecdsa.PrivateKey:
        bitLen = privKey.Curve.Params().BitSize
    default:
        log.Fatal("unsupported private key")
    }

    if bitLen < 2048 {
        log.Fatalf("private key length is too small (size: %d)\n", bitLen)
    }

    tlsConfig := tls.Config{
        Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
    }

    server := http.Server{
        Addr:      ":8080",
        TLSConfig: &tlsConfig,
    }
    if err := server.ListenAndServeTLS("", ""); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this will fail with any ECDSA key, because they use much smaller key sizes.